# PowerApps Images Upload when Offline

Tags: azure, powerapps

We are working on a scenario where User Captures the Images using PowerApps and the images are uploaded to Azure Data Lake. This works fine for Online Devices.

Offline Scenario:
User Captures Image > Image is Stored Locally/in Cache > Device gains Internet Connection > Locally Saved/Cached Images are pushed to Azure Data Lake.

Question: Is this possible? I think Inherently Azure PowerApps don't work offline caching. Is there a workaround this?

Comment: Can you check for network connectivity, and if there is none, store the images locally?
You would need a routine to upload these when network is available.
I've done this with collections and it works fine.

Comment: How many images can be stored locally in collections?

Comment: I'm not sure - it would depend on the memory specs of the phone.  I would've thought a few hundred easily, possibly a few thousands.  Also, depends on the size of the images - phones generate very high quality photos which could be several MBs each.

Comment: Thank you. Can you post this as answer? So I can upvote and mark as solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The number of images that can be stored locally in collections would depend on the memory specs of the phone. I would've thought a few hundred easily, possibly a few thousand.
Also, depends on the size of the images - phones generate very high quality photos which could be several MBs each.